# Populate and sort a ComboBox from another ComboBox, VBA

Tags: sorting, ms-access, combobox, vba

Hi Everyone I am having trouble getting a ComboBox to sort, when another combobox is selected.
I think I have the Right SQL Syntax but I cant seem to get the vba to run it through; currently the vba returns all of the states in the recordset regardless of the company.

```
Private Sub CboCountry_Click()
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim SQLStr As String

Set RsState = db.OpenRecordset("T2States", dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)

 'populates combobox with recordset, that is defined by the country input from the form

RsState.MoveFirst
Do While Not RsState.EOF
    Me.CboState.RowSource = Me.CboState.RowSource & RsState("StateID") & ";" & RsState("State") & ";"
    RsState.MoveNext
Loop
```

I think this is the right SQL String but I'm having trouble to get it to work.

```
'SQLStr = "SELECT T2States.StateID, T2States.States, T2States.CountryID" & _
            " FROM T2States GROUP BY T2States.StatesID" & _
            " WHERE T2States.CountryID = """ & Me.CboCountry.Value & """"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit#1
See Full Code below, the error that pops up when I substitute SQLStr into the Openrecordset is a Run-time error '3078' the microsoft access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'SQLStr'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.
What should happen is when a country is selected from CboCountry combobox, it will load the CboState combobox by sorting the recordset by CountryID

see below for both code parts

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()

Set db = CurrentDb
Set RsCompany = db.OpenRecordset("T1Company", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set RsCountry = db.OpenRecordset("T2Countries", dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
Set RsAddress = db.OpenRecordset("T1Addresses", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set RsAddressType = db.OpenRecordset("T2AddressType", dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
Set RsCompanyAddress = db.OpenRecordset("T3Company_Address", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

Me.CboCountry = Null
Me.TxtAddress1 = Null
Me.TxtAddress2 = Null
Me.TxtAddress3 = Null
Me.TxtCity = Null
Me.CboAddressType = Null
Me.CboCountry = Null
Me.CboState = Null
Me.TxtPostalCode = Null
Me.TxtCompanyID = Null
Me.TxtLegalName = Null
Me.TxtNickname = Null
Me.TxtAddressID = Null

    RsCountry.MoveFirst
    Do While Not RsCountry.EOF
        Me.CboCountry.RowSource = Me.CboCountry.RowSource & RsCountry("CountryID") & ";" & RsCountry("Country") & ";"
        RsCountry.MoveNext
    Loop

    RsAddressType.MoveFirst
    Do While Not RsAddressType.EOF
        Me.CboAddressType.RowSource = Me.CboAddressType.RowSource & RsAddressType("AddressTypeID") & ";" & RsAddressType("AddressType") & ";"
        RsAddressType.MoveNext
    Loop
Me.TxtLegalName.SetFocus

End Sub



Private Sub CboCountry_Click()
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim SQLStr As String

'SQLStr = "SELECT T2States.StateID, T2States.State, T2States.CountryID" & _
            " FROM T2States" & _
            " WHERE T2States.CountryID = """ & Me.CboCountry.Value & """"

Set RsState = db.OpenRecordset("T2States", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    'populates combobox with recordset, that is defined by the country input from the form

    RsState.MoveFirst
    Do While Not RsState.EOF
        Me.CboState.RowSource = Me.CboState.RowSource & RsState("StateID") & ";" & RsState("State") & ";"
        RsState.MoveNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us see

1- sure you've to append with

```
Having T2States.States, T2States.CountryID
```

2- Error exist in it, extra 's' in the Column name:

```
GROUP BY T2States.StatesID
```

3- put all the code and i'll check with you what you miss.

best regards

Comment: please see Edit #1, those are the applicable code, on form load the CboCountry is initialized, once the Country is selected from the combobox it should load CboState, but I get runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

This one turned out to be a quick fix in the Property Sheet under the DATA tab, the Row Source Type had to be changed back to 'Table/Query' from a 'Value'.

There is VBA that could account for this but it was just a simple as changing that Row Source.

The Reason for the mix up, for a quick bit of background if it helps, is that all my combo boxes are unbound and I was binding them with VBA Recordsets so the rowsource has to be a value list - Essentially the VBA is writing the list everytime it loads.

Where as when I started using SQL to generate the recordset, even though it was in VBA I had to change the property back to Table/Query.

Thanks.